# How can I burn an Apple Music playlist onto a CD?

Tags: itunes, apple-music

Looking to burn a CD and use songs from Apple Music.

Can I do this with only iTunes? Do I need 3rd party software?

Comment: What happens if you select the Burn option from the File menu?

Comment: You will need 3rd party software

Answer (score 1):

iTunes for Windows: Disc burning overview

> You can use iTunes to create your own CDs and DVDs with audio and
>   video from your iTunes library.
>
> Important: You can’t burn the following to CDs or DVDs:
>
> - Movies and TV shows purchased from the iTunes Store
> - Songs or music videos downloaded from Apple Music

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH20378?locale=en_US